# SQl calculate column value based on reference table

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join

I want to select  a column value based on the reference table in SQL Server.

These are the tables:

**Tbl1**

```
id   Cost   LineNo 
-----------------------
1     10      01
2     20      02
3     30      03
```

**Tbl2**

```
id  LineNo MaterialCost
--- -----  -----------
1    03     50
```

I want to calculate `Totalcost` (as `line no * Materialcost`) from `tbl2` if there is a matching lineno in `tbl2` from `tbl1` else get the TotalCost (`lineno * Cost`) from tbl1

Below is the output I want

```
id   Cost   LineNo          TotalCost
-----------------------     ---------
1     10      01             10
2     20      02             40
3     30      03            150
```

Comment: What if there is more than one matching row?

Answer (score 2):

In sql server, you can use this:

```
select Tbl1.id, 
        Tbl1.Cost, 
        Tbl1.LineNo, 
        Tbl1.LineNo * ISNULL(tbl2.MaterialCost, Tbl1.Cost)
from Tbl1 
left join Tbl2
on Tbl1.LineNo = Tbl2.LineNo
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `LEFT JOIN` and `coalesce` as follows:

```
select t1.*, (t1.lineNo * coalesce(t2.materialcost, t1.cost)) as total
  from table1 t1 
  left join table2 t2 on t1.lineno = t2.lineno
```